# Class Based View Reverse URL not reversing to URL with id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have different views trying to add a product for one member created on the app not a user with authentication more of a one admin management system. Below is my code kindly help much appreciated.

I get an error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'read_hairbty' with
> no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['read_hairbty/(?P[0-9]+)$']

Views.py

> ## Create Appointment

```
class HBTYOrderView(BSModalCreateView):
    model = HbtyOrder
    template_name = 'accounts/modals/hairbty/create_hbtyordr.html'
    form_class = HairbtyOrderForm
    success_message = 'Success: Appointment was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('read_hairbty')
```

## View Appointment

```
class HBTYReadView(generic.ListView):
    model = HbtyOrder
    context_object_name = 'hairbty'
    template_name = 'accounts/modals/hairbty/read_hbty.html'
    allow_empty = True
    pk_url_kwargs = 'hbtycustomer_id'
    paginate_by = 100
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(hbtycustomer_id=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('-date_created')
        p_f = HbtyOrdersFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
        return p_f.qs
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = HbtyOrdersFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context
```

> Urls.py

```
path('read_hairbty/<int:pk>', views.HBTYReadView.as_view(), name='read_hairbty'),

path('create_hairbtyorder/', views.HBTYOrderView.as_view(), name='create_hairbtyorder'),
```

Comment: Also share `HbtyOrder` model and it should be `pk_url_kwarg` not `pk_url_kwargs`.

Comment: Can you share the GitHub repo of project?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with [`get_success_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url).

```
class HBTYOrderView(BSModalCreateView):
    model = HbtyOrder
    template_name = 'accounts/modals/hairbty/create_hbtyordr.html'
    form_class = HairbtyOrderForm
    success_message = 'Success: Appointment was created.'
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('read_hairbty', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: Tried with the get_success_url i get same error: - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'read_hairbty' with keyword arguments '{'pk': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['read_hairbty/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class HBTYOrderView(BSModalCreateView):
    ...

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('read_hairbty', kwargs={'pk': self.object.hbtycustomer_id})
```

Comment: Tried with the get_success_url i get same error: - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'read_hairbty' with keyword arguments '{'pk': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['read_hairbty/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']. Thank You

Comment: @d3vkidhash I think the error is related to `HBTYReadView` view, when you are having this error, while displaying the records? And did you notice `pk_url_kwargs`? Also share model for reference, if possible.

Comment: Thank You My Model
class HbtyOrder(models.Model):
 
categ = models.ForeignKey(HbtyCategories, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
 subcateg = models.ForeignKey(HbtySubcategories, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
 hbtycustomer = models.ForeignKey(HbtyCustomers, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
 date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
 
 def __str__(self):
  return str(self.id)
 
 def get_absolute_url(self):
  return reverse('read_hairbty', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

Comment: @d3vkidhash Can you please edit that model in the question?

Comment: Looking at your model, `hbtycustomer_id` could be null. In `HBTYReadView`, the queryset you want is filtered by `hbtycustomer_id`. If `hbtycustomer_id` is null, you cannot go to `HBTYReadView`. Add behavior when `self.object.hbtycustomer_id` is null in `get_success_url()`

Comment: And your `pk_url_kwargs` is not used. Because instead you used `self.kwargs['pk']`.

Comment: kindly help in Adding a behaviour when self.objectt.hbtycustomer_id in null in get_success_url().Thank You

Comment: It's hard to know what behavior your application wants. When creating HbtyOrder, what kind of screen do you want to show if hbtycustomer_id is null? Do you want to utilize HBTYReadView to display a list of HbtyOrders with hbtycustomer_id null?

Comment: i understand, want to have a message saying empty orders when hbtycustomer_id is null, something like that

Comment: It looks like you used blank=True, null=True indiscriminately in your model.
do you really want hbtycustomer_id to be nullable?

Comment: i have changed my hbtycustomers code to blank=false and null=true because of the on_delete=models.SET_NULL but i can not post, one thing to consider is if i add the hbtycustomer fileds to the form it becomes visible and i am able to see and select the customer  and able to sumbit the form and see the correct results in the same reverse url.Thank You